# How can I abort building in CLion?

Tags: clion

Once I click on the "build" button I don't seem to have a way of stopping the build progress. I have a project with several thousand source files and if I find out something is wrong, my only solution seems to be to kill or quit CLion and start over, and of course wait around 10 minutes for it to load the project again. Is there a magic hot key to abort the build?

Answer (score 2):

There's an interrupt button right to the progress indicator in the status bar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use clion to create cmake-build-debug directory and you don't want it to compile your code by clion everytime you change and start clion, you can remove the cmake profile from

```
File->Setting->Build,Execution,Deployment->CMake
```

And use (-) symbol to remove the profile.